# How to set alarm for selected days in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I want to set alarm for selected days of the week.

It may be a weekday (mon, tue, wed, thu, or fri), weekend(sat, sun) or daily.

How can i do this using local notifications?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) and [Local Notification Tutorial](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/). also check this [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the time which you have to fire notification every day, you should do this

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    for (NSMutableArray * arrDay in self.namaztimes) {
        NSLog(@"Alarm Array: %@", arrDay);
        int count=[arrDay count];
        if(!count){
            continue;
        }

        int day =0;
        int month=0;
        int year=0;
        int hour =0;
        int minutes=0;

        //  NSArray *arrDates=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        for ( int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            NSString * dayTime=[arrDay objectAtIndex:i ];
            if (i==0) {
                day = [dayTime intValue];    
            }else if(i==1){
                month = [dayTime intValue];                    
            }else if(i==2){
                year = [dayTime intValue];    

            }
        }
        for ( int i=3;i<count;i++) {
            NSString * dayTime=[arrDay objectAtIndex:i ];
            hour = [[dayTime substringToIndex:2] intValue];
            minutes = [[dayTime substringFromIndex:3] intValue];

            [components setDay:day];
            [components setMonth:month];
            [components setYear:year];
            [components setMinute:minutes];
            [components setHour:hour];


            NSDate *myNewDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

            [self scheduleNotificationForDate:myNewDate];

        }
    }

    [components release];
    [calendar release];
```

then from here it will connect to the main notification firing method
      `[self scheduleNotificationForDate:myNewDate];`

```
-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate: (NSDate*)date {
    /* Here we cancel all previously scheduled notifications */
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = date;
    NSLog(@"Notification will be shown on: %@ ",localNotification.fireDate);

    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Your Notification Text"; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date];
    localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View details", nil);

    /* Here we set notification sound and badge on the app's icon "-1" 
     means that number indicator on the badge will be decreased by one 
     - so there will be no badge on the icon */

    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: Hi sree charan, thanks I want to set alarm for selected days only .How can i do this?

Comment: customize my code, i have already given the int values for all calendar events, day,month, year,hour etc, just send your values dynamically to this method

Comment: It means,is it possible to give the day values from an array and what is self.namaztimes?(is this alarm time.)

Comment: yes, you can do that, customize the method and send parameters to this method.

Comment: it is the array in which i have the dates which are to be fired,i mean with full date format with time also

Comment: i did the same what you said but app crashes when i'm getting the count of the array here for (NSMutableArray * arrDay in arrAlarm)

Comment: you should not do blidly what i have told, you need to analyse your code and take what ever you want from my code, i have just given a good idea to fire local notifications

Comment: i did the same what you said but app crashes when i'm getting the count of the array here for (NSMutableArray * arrDay in arrAlarm).Can i have the complete code.

Comment: I'm getting the local notification.but not for the selected days.thats my prob?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked long ago, i am adding this because it will helpful for some one.

If your want to notify for selected days then follow this [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/). It will helpful.