# Perform selector at specific time

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to execute my method at midnight, but I haven't idea how to do this correctly. Check time every minute and if current time is equal 23:59 run method looks stupid. Calculate time interval from now to midnight and set it as parameter to nstimer?

Can you help me with this problem?

UPDATE:
Sorry, guys, I forgot one thing about this: method have to run background without any user notification.

Comment: the following services can run in the background only: `location services`, `VoIP` and `audio`, every other thread will be suspended when the application goes to the background or the device goes to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Local Notification:

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notif.soundName = @"sound.wav";
notif.alertBody = @"My Message";
notif.alertAction = @"Open";

// you need to configure interval and firedate to schedule everything
notif.repeatInterval = XXX;
notif.repeatCalendar = XXX;
notif.fireDate       = XXX;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notif];

[notif release];
```

To detect when app opened from notification, you need to implement in your App Delegate these methods:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

hope this helps.

---

AFTER YOUR EDIT:

You can use `[NSTimer ScheduleTimerWith.....]` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Local Notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) scheduled at some time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780517/how-to-set-alarm-for-selected-days-in-iphone